# Reorder source Spark dataframe columns to match the order of the target dataframe in PySpark

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a fixed Spark DataFrame order from the target table:

> Target Spark Dataframe(col1 string , col2 int , col3 string , col4 double)

Now, if the source data comes in a jumbled order:

> Source Spark Dataframe(col3 string , col2 int ,col4 double , col1 string).

How can I rearrange the source DataFrame to match the column order of the target DataFrame using PySpark?

The Source  Spark Dataframe should be reordered like below to match the target DataFrame:

Output:

> Updated Source Spark Dataframe(col1 string , col2 int , col3 string , col4 double)

Scenario 2:

> Source Dataframe =[a,c,d,e]
>
> Target dataframe =[a,b,c,d]

In this scenario, the source DataFrame should be rearranged to `[a,b,c,d,e]`

- Keep the order of the target columns
- Change the datatypes of the source column to match the target dataframe
- Add the new columns at the end
- If the target column is not present in the source columns, then the column should still be added but filled with `null` values.

In the above example, after the source DataFrame is rearranged, it would have a `b` column added with `null` values.

This will ensure that when we use `saveAsTable`, the source DataFrame can easily be pushed into the table without breaking the existing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you had the following two DataFrames:

```python
source.show()
#+---+---+---+---+
#|  a|  c|  d|  e|
#+---+---+---+---+
#|  A|  C|  0|  E|
#+---+---+---+---+

target.show()
#+---+---+---+---+
#|  a|  b|  c|  d|
#+---+---+---+---+
#|  A|  B|  C|  1|
#+---+---+---+---+
```

With the following data types:

```python
print(source.dtypes)
#[('a', 'string'), ('c', 'string'), ('d', 'string'), ('e', 'string')]

print(target.dtypes)
#[('a', 'string'), ('b', 'string'), ('c', 'string'), ('d', 'int')]
```

If I understand your logic correctly, the following list comprehension should work for you:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit

new_source = source.select(
    *(
        [
            col(t).cast(d) if t in source.columns else lit(None).alias(t) 
            for t, d in target.dtypes
        ] +
        [s for s in source.columns if s not in target.columns]
    )
)

new_source.show()

new_source.show()
#+---+----+---+---+---+
#|  a|   b|  c|  d|  e|
#+---+----+---+---+---+
#|  A|null|  C|  0|  E|
#+---+----+---+---+---+
```

And the resulting output will have the following schema:

```python
new_source.printSchema()
#root
# |-- a: string (nullable = true)
# |-- b: null (nullable = true)
# |-- c: string (nullable = true)
# |-- d: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- e: string (nullable = true)
```

As you can see, column `d`'s datatype changed from `string` to `integer` to match the target table's schema.

The logic is to first loop over the columns in `target` and select them if they exist in `source.columns` or create a column of `null`s if it doesn't exist. Then add in the columns from `source` that don't exist in `target`.

Comment: ..is there a way to cast the newly created column to match the schema of the target dataframe .Else , union may lead to issues of the source and the target dataframes?I can create a new question if required .Please suggest

Comment: I Source Schema
StructType(List(StructField(name,StringType,true),StructField(field1,LongType,true),StructField(seq_num,IntegerType,true)))
Target Schema
StructType(List(StructField(name,StringType,true),StructField(age,StringType,true),StructField(field1,StringType,true),StructField(hiveserde,StringType,true),StructField(seq_num,IntegerType,true)))
new Source Schema
StructType(List(StructField(name,StringType,true),StructField(age,NullType,true),StructField(field1,StringType,true),StructField(hiveserde,NullType,true),StructField(seq_num,IntegerType,true)))

Comment: If you see ...the new source Schema  is assigning NullType to age even though teh target is String.That should not be the case

Comment: that would need to match , so that the source and the targets can be used to union

Comment: Probably best if you edited this into the question, formatted as code. Or create a new question. Make sure you include a [mcve], ideally something small we can cut and paste to recreate your issue.

Comment: Sure will do and tag you in..Thanks